# what index do I need when I use DISTINCT with Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

with the following view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW {accountId}.last_assets AS
SELECT DISTINCT ON (coin) * from {accountId}.{tableAssetsName} ORDER BY coin, ts DESC;"
```

I want to get the latest of all rows with different 'coin' values. In short, the latest update of each coin.

Should I index *(ts)* and *(coin)* separately ? or should I index together *(ts, coin)*?
(and why?)

Comment: Note: DISTINCT is always a red flag. (almost always)

Comment: @wildplasser what would be an alternative way to reach the same goal? (Latest update for each coin)

Comment: Commands that won't run do not need indexes.  `ERROR:  SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions`

Comment: @jjanes, I did an edit fixing it, I had forgotten one parameter in the order by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an index on `(coin, ts)` in this order.

It is not guaranteed that PostgreSQL will use it, but it is the best index for the query.